# How can I escape a ';' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-entities

I am trying to write an algorithm where I replace characters like `&`, `<`, `>`, , `'`, `"` with their HTML entity counterpart(i.e. `&` would be replaced with `&amp;`. This requires me to put a semi-colon in a string, which creates an error because Javascript thinks that I have ended the line. Here is my code:

```
str.charAt(i) = '&amp;';
```

I thought that I could cancel it like so:

```
str.charAt(i) = '&amp\;';
```

but this creates an error.

Comment: Semi-colons inside string literals do not terminate statements in JavaScript. You are misinterpreting whatever problem you are having.

Comment: `;` isn't an html metacharacter. it's meaning unless unless preceeded with an `&`, so it by itself doesn't need to be escaped. and `;` inside a string doesn't terminate the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your assignment is invalid. You seem to be trying to mutate a string, which is impossible in JS since strings are immutable.

Instead you need to create a new string with the parts you want replaced with the new content.

```
var new_str = s.replace(/(?:(&)|(<)|(>)|(')|("))/g, function(s, g1,g2,g3,g4,g5) {
    if (g1) return "&amp;"
    if (g2) return "&lt;"
    if (g3) return "&gt;"
    if (g4) return "&apos;"
    if (g5) return "&quot;"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Semi-colons inside string literals do not terminate statements in JavaScript.

> ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Your problem is that you are trying to assign a value to the return value of a function, which isn't allowed.

If you want to replace characters in a string, use the `replace` method.

In this case, you are trying to convert a string of text into a string of HTML and it is simpler to let the DOM do that for you:

```
var div_node = document.createElement('div');
var text_node = document.createTextNode(str);
div_node.appendChild(text_node);
var str_html = div_node.innerHTML;
```

Note that this won't replace *all* of the characters. Some don't need escaping all the time.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape semicolons inside strings.  JavaScript doesn't think the line has ended in a string any more than it thinks the line ended inside `for (var i = 0; ...)`.

Comment: Thank you, somehow, I was receiving an error for the semi-colon being an unrecognized character.

Comment: Unless you do. There are many formats that use a semicolon to separate elements.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't an escaping issue.  It's that you're attempting to assign a value to the static output of the `String.charAt()` method, which is not allowed.

Instead, try using the string replace method to replace your HTML entities with alternative values.

```
s = 'Hello & World';
s.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;');
```

Comment: That's only going to replace the first one, and he is also trying to replace `<`, `>` and `"` and `'`.

Comment: @Quentin - nevertheless, it demonstrates a solution to the problem in the code he posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a function to replace characters by their HTML entities:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
}
```

`;` don't need any replacement.